# Can I create an new instance of my custom managed object class without going through NSEntityDescription?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, core-data, macos

From an Apple example, I have this:

```
Event *event = (Event*)[NSEntityDescription 
    insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Event" 
             inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

`Event` inherits from `NSManagedObject`. Is there a way to avoid this weird call to NSEntityDescription and instead just `alloc+init` somehow directly the `Event` class? Would I have to write my own initializer that just does that stuff above? Or is `NSManagedObject` already intelligent enough to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NSManagedObject` provides a method called [`initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-BBCFJIEEhttp://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-BBCFJIEE). You can use this to do a more traditional `alloc`/`init` pair. Keep in mind that the object this returns is *not* autoreleased.

Comment: Oh yeah, but don't ever override `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`. `awakeFromInsert` is the appropriate place to do initialization.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into the exact same problem. It turns out you can completely create an entity and not add it to the store at first, then make some checks on it and if everything is good insert it into the store. I use it during an XML parsing session where I only want to insert entities once they have been properly and entirely parsed.

First you need to create the entity:

```
// This line creates the proper description using the managed context and entity name. 
// Note that it uses the managed object context
NSEntityDescription *ent = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Location" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedContext]];

// This line initialized the entity but does not insert it into the managed object context.    
currentEntity = [[Location alloc] initWithEntity:ent insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil];
```

Then once you are happy with the processing you can simply insert your entity into the store:

```
[self managedContext] insertObject:currentEntity
```

Note that in those examples the currentEntity object has been defined in a header file as follows:

```
id currentEntity
```

Answer (score 1):

To get it to work properly, there is a LOT of stuff to do. -insertNewObject:... is by far the easiest way, weird or not. [The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654) says:

> A managed object differs from other
>   objects in three main ways—a managed
>   object ... Exists in an environment
>   defined by its managed object context
>   ... there is therefore a lot of work
>   to do to create a new managed object
>   and properly integrate it into the
>   Core Data infrastructure ... you are
>   discouraged from overriding
>   initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:

That said, you can still do it (read further down the page to which I linked) but your goal appears to be "easier" or "less weird". I'd say the method you feel is weird is actually the simplest, most normal way.

Answer (score 1):

I found a definitive answer from *More iPhone 3 Development* by Dave Mark and Jeff LeMarche.

If it really bothers you that you use a method on `NSEntityDescrpiton` rather than on `NSManagedObjectContext` to insert a new object into an `NSManagedObjectContext`, you can **use a category** to add an instance method to `NSManagedObjectContext`.

Create two new text files called *NSManagedObject-Insert.h* and *NSManagedObject-Insert.m*.

In *NSManagedObject-Insert.h*, place the following code:

```
import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface NSManagedObjectContext (insert)
- (NSManagedObject *)insertNewEntityWithName:(NSString *)name;
@end
```

In *NSManagedObject-Insert.m*, place this code:

```
#import "NSManagedObjectContext-insert.h"

@implementation NSManagedObjectContext (insert)
- (NSManagedObject *)insertNewEntityWithName:(NSString *)name
{
return [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:self];
}
@end
```

You can import *NSManagedObject-Insert.h* anywhere you wish to use this new method. Then replace the insert calls against `NSEntityDescription`, like this one:

```
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

with the shorter and more intuitive one:

```
[context insertNewEntityWithName:[entity name]];
```

Aren't categories grand?